# Splitting String to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to split the string to dictionary. String is taken by using

```
$ sudo btmgmt find |grep rssi |sort -n |uniq -w 33
```

and my result is

```
hci0 dev_found: 40:43:42:B3:71:11 type LE Random rssi -53 flags 0x0000 
hci0 dev_found: 44:DA:5F:EA:C6:CF type LE Random rssi -78 flags 0x0000
```

The goal is creating dictionary where key is MAC address and value is rssi value

```
dict = {
    "40:43:42:B3:71:11": "-53 ",
    "44:DA:5F:EA:C6:CF": "-78",
   }
```

I tried a lot of replace function to replace these Strings to empty Strings:

- hci0 dev_found:
- type
- LE
- Random
- rssi

But it must be cleaner and better way to do this dictionary and I do not see this solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: if every line has the same construction then you can `split(" ")` line to list of items and use items in list to create element in dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every line has the same construction then you can use `split()` to split text into lines and later to split every line into "words" which you can use to create element in dictionary:

```
s = """
hci0 dev_found: 40:43:42:B3:71:11 type LE Random rssi -53 flags 0x0000 
hci0 dev_found: 44:DA:5F:EA:C6:CF type LE Random rssi -78 flags 0x0000
"""

d = dict()

for line in s.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip() # clear spaces and enters
    if line: # skip empty lines
        words = line.split(' ')
        d[words[2]] = words[7]

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` with regex lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
import re
s = """
hci0 dev_found: 40:43:42:B3:71:11 type LE Random rssi -53 flags 0x0000 
hci0 dev_found: 44:DA:5F:EA:C6:CF type LE Random rssi -78 flags 0x0000
"""
d = dict([re.findall('(?<=dev_found:\s)[A-Z\d:]+|[\-\d]+(?=\sflags)', i) for i in filter(None, s.split('\n'))])
```

Output:

```
{'40:43:42:B3:71:11': '-53', '44:DA:5F:EA:C6:CF': '-78'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the columns are separated by spaces, you can use the split method:

```
s = """hci0 dev_found: 40:43:42:B3:71:11 type LE Random rssi -53 flags 0x0000 
hci0 dev_found: 44:DA:5F:EA:C6:CF type LE Random rssi -78 flags 0x0000"""

sdic = {}

for line in s.split('\n'):
    column = line.split(' ')
    sdic[column[2]] = column[7]

print(sdic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Input: a file with given lines

```
import re
d = dict()
c1 = re.compile("((\d|\w){1,2}:){5}(\d|\w){1,2}")
c2 = re.compile(r"(-\d{2}) flags")
with open("your_saved_lines.txt") as fh:
  for l in fh.readlines():
    m1 = c1.search(l)
    m2 = c2.search(l) or "NA"
    if m1:
      d[m1.group()] = m2.group(1)
print(d)
```

Output: `{'40:43:42:B3:71:11': '-53', '44:DA:5F:EA:C6:CF': '-78'}`